# How to center merged rows vertically?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I want to center the merged rows `ac` vertically. How to do so?

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\newcommand{\cell}[2]{%
    $\displaystyle
    \begin{array}{c}
     {} #1 m \\
     {} #2 n
    \end{array}$}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$ac$}} &
            $+$ &
            \cell{+}{+} &
            \cell{-}{-} \\\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
            $-$ &
            \cell{-}{+} &
            \cell{+}{-} \\\hline                                            
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &
            $+$ &
            $-$ \\\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &
            \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$b$}    \\\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `multirow` can take any number of rows as an option for fine tuning -- have a look below -- `\multirow{3.1}{*}{$ac$}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unnecessarily complicated:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|>{ $}c<{$ }}|}\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{$ac$} & \multirow{2}{*}{+}    & +\ m  & -\ m \\
                      &                       & +\ n  & -\ n \\\cline{2-4}
                      &  \multirow{2}{*}{$-$} & +\ m  & -\ m \\
                      &                       & +\ n  & -\ n \\\cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                         & +    & -    \\\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{b} \\\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It took a lot of time to think which answer should be accepted. And finally Albert Einstein inspired me to choose the simpler solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can do easily that tabular with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In `{NiceTabular}`, you merge cells both horizontally and vertically with the command `\Block`. For the rows, you give the number of *logical* rows (and not the number of physical lines as with `\multicolumn`).

With the key `hvlines`, all the rules are drawn, excepted in the blocks (constructed by `\Block`) and in the corners specified by the key `corners` (the corners are computed automatically).

```
\documentclass[preview,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\newcommand{\cell}[2]{%
    $\displaystyle
    \begin{array}{c}
     {} #1 m \\
     {} #2 n
    \end{array}$}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines,corners=SW]% SW : south west
\Block{2-1}{$ac$} &
            $+$ &
            \cell{+}{+} &
            \cell{-}{-} \\
&
            $-$ &
            \cell{-}{+} &
            \cell{+}{-} \\
& &         $+$ &
            $-$ \\
& & \Block{1-2}{$b$}    \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\newcommand{\cell}[2]{%
    $\displaystyle
    \begin{array}{c}
        {} #1 m \\
        {} #2 n
    \end{array}$}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}\hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3.1}{*}{$ac$}} &
        $+$ &
        \cell{+}{+} &
        \cell{-}{-} \\\cline{2-4}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
        $-$ &
        \cell{-}{+} &
        \cell{+}{-} \\\hline                                            
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &
        $+$ &
        $-$ \\\cline{3-4}
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$b$}    \\\cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is approximation -- you can bracket it by using 2 and then 4 and then narrow down to 3.1 -- 3.2 will take it a bit too far down

Comment: The exact value is `$\sqrt{10}$`. I think. :-)

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer  would you like to accept the answer and upvote the answer if it meets the requirement projected in the question

Comment: As usual, it will take a couple of hours, days, months, years, decades, or maybe centuries to decide the accepted answer. Please be patient. :-)

Comment: not an issue -- however do let us know if the answer meets the projected requirement -- `I want to center the merged rows ac vertically.` -- do let us know if there was any other requirement projected which was not addressed -- thank you for the eons

Comment: @MakeMeSmarterEveryDay You are lucky that user js bibra is less patient in providing answers :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Sadly I have to choose the simpler one. Thank you @ js bibra for your contribution. :-)